# How to solve this problem with given method?

Tags: algorithms

There is a method

[image]

```
using System;
int[] A = {7,1,1,2,1,1,2,6,3,7};
int d = 0;
for(int i=1; i<A.Length; ++i)
{
    bool B = true;
    for(int j=0; j<d; ++j)
    {
        if(A[i]==A[j])
        {
            B = false;
            j= d;
        }
    }
    if(B)
    {
        d++;
        A[d] = A[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", A));
```

But anyway I have no idea how to answer these questions:

1. Write what method returns and prove that you right.
2. Give the execution time

Any ideas appreciate:)

Comment: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) would seem a more-appropriate place for coding/algorithm questions like this.

Comment: @Blue I think this question match to this channel. There is no questions about the code, there is one question about `what execution time` like (ex: ) O(n) or O(logn) and another question about `What the output`